# MobX Updating a decorated object inside a decorated array property doesn't emit reaction

Tags: mobx

I wrote a React prototype for a pay rates field that I'm working on, and now I'm trying to lift state up to a domain store for it. Right now, I'm just trying to test for reactions in the console, but for some reason, reactions aren't working when using an action to change a field of the observable array for that store.

**Code**

I have the following :

*data object*

```
class PayRate {
  /**
   * @param {number} taskId The id of the task. (-1 for all)
   * @param {Date} effectiveDate The date the payrate goes in effect.
   * @param {number} rate The rate of pay.
   */
  constructor(taskId, effectiveDate, rate) {
    this.TaskId = taskId || -1;
    this.EffectiveDate = effectiveDate ? new Date(effectiveDate) : new Date();
    this.Rate = rate || 0.00;
    this.OriginalObject = Object.assign({}, this);
  }

  /**
   * Gets a readable version of the effective date.
   * @returns {string} A -m/dd/yyyy representation of the effective date.
   */
  GetReadableDate() {
    return this.EffectiveDate.toLocaleDateString("en-US");
  }
  /**
   * Gets a one line description of the pay rate.
   * @returns {string} A string in the form of (date) - payrate.
   */
  GetDescription() {
    return `(${this.GetReadableDate()}) - $${this.Rate.toFixed(2)}`;
  }
  /**
   * Gets a one line description of the pay rate.
   * Does the exact same as GetDescription(), but is overload of Object.prototype.toString, which allows for stringification of Objects
   * @returns {string} A string in the form of (date) - payrate.
   */
  toString() {
    return `(${this.GetReadableDate()}) - $${this.Rate.toFixed(2)}`;
  }
  /**
   * Tells whether a pay rate was changed or not.
   * @returns {boolean} A boolean saying whether or not the pay rate was changed.
   */
  IsChanged() {
    if (this.EffectiveDate.getTime() !== this.OriginalObject.EffectiveDate.getTime()) {
      return true;
    }
    if (this.Rate != this.OriginalObject.Rate) {
      return true;
    }
    if (this._deleted) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
  /**
   * Reverts the changes back to the original.
   */
  RevertChanges() {
    Object.assign(this, this.OriginalObject);
  }
}

// mobx decorations
mobx.decorate(PayRate, {
  TaskId : mobx.observable,
  EffectiveDate : mobx.observable,
  Rate : mobx.observable,
})
```

**Domain store**

```
class PayRatesStore { 
    constructor() { 
        this.payRates = [];

        this.payRateIndex = -1;

        this._dateString = '';

        this.payRateIndicesToDelete = [];

        mobx.autorun(() => {
            console.log(this.payRates)
            console.log(this.currentPayRate)
        })
    }

    // getters
    get currentPayRate() { 
        if ((this.payRates) && (this.payRates.length)) {
            return this.payRates[this.payRateIndex];
        }
        return new PayRate();
    }

    get dateString() { 
        if (!this._dateString) { 
            if (this.currentPayRate) { 
                return this.currentPayRate.GetReadableDate()
            }
            return "";
        }
        return this._dateString;
    }

    set dateString(str) { 
        this._dateString = str;
    }

    updateCurrentPayRateDate(dateString) { 
        // update _dateString
        this._dateString = dateString

        this.payRates[this.payRateIndex].EffectiveDate = new Date(dateString)
    }
}

mobx.decorate(PayRatesStore, {
    payRates : mobx.observable,
    payRateIndex : mobx.observable,
    _dateString : mobx.observable,
    payRateIndicesToDelete : mobx.observable,
    currentPayRate : mobx.computed,
    dateString : mobx.computed,
    updateCurrentPayRateDate : mobx.action.bound
})
```

Setting up the `PayRatesStore` causes reactions as we expect:

```
let payRate = new PayRate(1, "03/25/2019", 15.5),
  payRates = [ payRate ]
// create PayRatesStore
let payRatesStore = new PayRatesStore()
console.log("Passing data to pay rates store....")
  payRatesStore.payRates = payRates
  payRatesStore.payRateIndex = 0
```

causes the following to be `console.log`ged:

[image]

However, when I try:

```
payRatesStore.updateCurrentPayRateDate('4/1/2019')
```

Nothing happens; // MobX doesn't react!!

I don't know what I can do to get MobX to react to this, as it was lifted up from the React Component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you misunderstand how autorun works.
autorun subscribes to changes in the values of the variables that are referenced in the function.

#### What is happening

Here, your autorun function is observing `payRates` and `currentPayRate`.

**The first time**, you modify both `payRates` and `currentPayRate` (because you change payRateIndex, it updates the computed property `currentPayRate`).

-> autorun reacted.

**The second time**, you modify an element property in the payRates array, not the value of this.payRates itself, it is still the same array. So, `payRates` did not change, nor `currentPayRate`.

-> autorun does not react.

#### More about autorun

Autorun won't subscribe to "nested" array elements. For more details, you could read this: [Watch for nested object/array changes](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx/issues/1207)

Comment: What should I do w.r.t. this instead? I was able to get this working by changing the action logic to **overwrite** that array element, but that seems a roundabout way of emitting simple element property changes. Will I need to do it this way, for any property change?

Comment: That is a different question. You probably need to rethink how to structure your app / models and think about the responsibilities of each of those. Someone also mentions this in the link I have posted.

Comment: Ya, I went to play around with the [Ten minute tutorial](https://mobx.js.org/getting-started.html), by inserting the `observable` index I have going on in my store into theirs. It caused this issue I am facing!

Unfortunately, with the business requirements of my app (click on a pay rate, its info pops up in the fields, and when the fields are edited, that pay rate updates), seems to require it, else I would have to write a lot more code to make things like simple selections work.